# How do I insert a new line of text in a specific area of an xml file using cmd?

Tags: xml, cmd

I have several XML files. I need to add new text to the second line and last line of each one.
How can I do this using cmd?

Thank you

edit:new example

Suppose I have several xml files in folder C:\Users\agarr\XMLfiles:

I have a file that looks this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MediaAsset>
    <Original>
          <AssetIdentifier>S13_African_Art_tour_gallery_4583</AssetIdentifier>
    </Original>
</MediaAsset>
```

Now I want it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MediaAssets>
    <MediaAsset>
        <Original>
          <AssetIdentifier>S13_African_Art_tour_gallery_4583</AssetIdentifier>
        </Original>
    </MediaAsset>
</MediaAssets>
```

I want to create a new first element.

Simpler example:
I want this

```
1
3
4
```

To be come this

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Indenting XML tags is not required for parsing, if I understand things correctly. I just need to add information to the second and last lines of every XML file I have, no exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `cmd` itself, nor the standard tools it comes with, support XML. This can't be done.

I think many people would resort to PowerShell, but there are alternatives, like the Swiss-knife-tool [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).

XML output:

```
xidel -s input.xml -e "(<MediaAssets>{.}</MediaAssets>)"     --output-format=xml --output-declaration='^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?^>'   --output-node-indent
xidel -s input.xml --xquery "<MediaAssets>{.}</MediaAssets>" --output-format=xml --output-declaration="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" --output-node-indent
xidel -s input.xml -e "element MediaAssets {.}"              --output-format=xml --output-declaration="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" --output-node-indent
```

Serialized XML (text) output:

```
xidel -s input.xml -e "serialize(<MediaAssets>{.}</MediaAssets>,{'indent':true(),'omit-xml-declaration':false()})"
xidel -s input.xml -e "serialize(element MediaAssets {.},{'indent':true(),'omit-xml-declaration':false()})"
```

Output in all cases:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MediaAssets>
  <MediaAsset>
    <Original>
      <AssetIdentifier>S13_African_Art_tour_gallery_4583</AssetIdentifier>
    </Original>
  </MediaAsset>
</MediaAssets>
```

- With `--output-format=xml` the "encoding"-attribute of the XML-declaration inherits `cmd`'s active [code page](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html), which most likely isn't "UTF-8". So you have to manually set the XML-declaration with `--output-declaration="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"`.
- If the query with `-e` starts with a `<`, then Xidel will use [pattern matching](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html#examples). For "[direct element constructors](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-element-constructor)" (`<MediaAssets>{.}</MediaAssets>`) put parentheses around the query, or use `--xquery`. For "[computed constructors](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-computedConstructors)" (`element MediaAssets {.}`) this is no issue.
- `--output-node-indent` requires [Xidel 0.9.9 (20211123.8232.023d1f1f656e)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/) or later.
- [`serialize()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#fn-serialize) accepts options as a JSON object, like `{'indent':true()}` for instance.
- With `{'omit-xml-declaration':false()}` the value of the "encoding"-attribute is always "UTF-8".

As long single lines of code can be hard to read, I'll prettify two commands/queries (including the required escape-characters):

```
xidel -s input.xml -e "element MediaAssets {.}" ^
--output-declaration="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" ^
--output-format=xml --output-node-indent

xidel -s input.xml -e ^"^
  serialize(^
    ^<MediaAssets^>{.}^</MediaAssets^>,^
    {'indent':true(),'omit-xml-declaration':false()}^
  )^
"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Windows platform, using PowerShell it is easy to achieve the required document transformation using XSLT.

```
PS> Get-Context "transform.xsl"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <MediaAssets>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </MediaAssets>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

PS> $xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
PS> $xslt.Load("transform.xsl")
PS> $xslt.Transform("input.xml", "output.xml")

PS> Get-Context "output.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MediaAssets>
  <MediaAsset>
    <Original>
          <AssetIdentifier>S13_African_Art_tour_gallery_4583</AssetIdentifier>
    </Original>
  </MediaAsset>
</MediaAssets>
```

If you are on a Linux platform you can use `xsltproc` to perform the document modification.

```
$ xsltproc transform.xsl input.xml > output.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of modifying your sample document is to use PowerShell to manipulate the DOM.

```
PS> Get-Context "demo1.ps1"
$xmldoc = New-Object xml
$xmldoc.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$xmldoc.Load("input.xml")

$node = $xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/MediaAsset")
$tmp = $node.CloneNode($true)
$null = $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)

$parent = $xmldoc.CreateElement("MediaAssets")
$null = $xmldoc.AppendChild($parent)

$node = $xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/MediaAssets")
$null = $node.AppendChild($tmp)

$xmldoc.Save("output.xml")

# output the modified XML to console. Any of the following work
# Write-Output "$($xmldoc.OuterXml)"
# Write-Output $xmldoc.OuterXml
$xmldoc.OuterXml
```

This produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MediaAssets><MediaAsset>
    <Original>
          <AssetIdentifier>S13_African_Art_tour_gallery_4583</AssetIdentifier>
    </Original>
</MediaAsset></MediaAssets>
```

If you want the new tags to be on their own separate lines you can use `CreateSignificantWhitespace` to do so.

```
PS> Get-Context "demo2.ps1"
$xmldoc = New-Object xml
$xmldoc.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$xmldoc.Load("input.xml")

$node = $xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/MediaAsset")
$tmp = $node.CloneNode($true)
$null = $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)

$parent = $xmldoc.CreateElement("MediaAssets")
$null = $xmldoc.AppendChild($parent)

$sigws1 = $xmldoc.CreateSignificantWhitespace("`n")
$sigws2 = $xmldoc.CreateSignificantWhitespace("`n")

$node = $xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/MediaAssets")
$null = $node.AppendChild($sigws1)
$null = $node.AppendChild($tmp)
$null = $node.AppendChild($sigws2)

$xmldoc.Save("output.xml")

$xmldoc.OuterXml
```

This produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MediaAssets>
<MediaAsset>
    <Original>
          <AssetIdentifier>S13_African_Art_tour_gallery_4583</AssetIdentifier>
    </Original>
</MediaAsset>
</MediaAssets>
```